# Using 'distinct' in a MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I have the following query.

```
SELECT p.author_name, p.author_id,
DISTINCT p.topic_id, t.title
FROM `ibf_posts` p, `ibf_topics` t
WHERE p.topic_id = t.tid
ORDER BY pid DESC
LIMIT 8"
```

When I run it, I get the following MySQL Error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DISTINCT p.topic_id, t.title FROM `ibf_posts` p, `ibf_topics` t WHERE p' at line 1
```

if I remove the `DISTINCT` keyword, then the query works without a problem.

What am I doing wrong?

This scheme is from Invision Power Board post and topic table. I am trying to get the title of the last 8 topics which has the newest posts. In the list of top latest posts, I don't want the same topic to appear more than once. I want a unique list of titles.

table: ibf_posts
-pid
-author_name
-author_id
-topic_id

table: ibf_topics
-tid
-title

tid is same as topic_id

Answer (score 7):

It's

```
SELECT DISTINCT ...
```

You can't specify `DISTINCT` only for a single column; it only works for keeping complete duplicate records out of the result set.

Answer (score 0):

Distinct needs to be before p.author_name.  You can't choose only p.topic_id to be distinct in this case.  If what you're wanting to do is what I think it is, you should look up the  GROUP BY clause.

Comment: I have tried GROUP BY and it did not give me correct set of rows.