# Sorting the SQL data Using DISTINCT

Tags: php, mysql

I was trying to build a chat plugin in my site but I got problem while sorting the incoming messages in the Inbox. When I use the code below, it doesn't order the messages according to new sent but orders according to history of sent messages:

E.g. if I send message to "A" at first, "B" after that and "C" at last, the code I works fine up to here. It shows C at Top, B at middle and A at end. But When I again send message to B, the "B" doesn't come up at the top.

**Edit:**
Someone tagged this question as duplicate. The problem about that question is abit different. I already did extract the unique row (as asked by that question) but I cannot sort it according to time.

Here is the code I use and please ignore the mysql_* tag I used here. It is just for testing.

```
<?php

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT `from` FROM `message` WHERE `to`='$username' ORDER BY `time` DESC");

// using loop

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
echo $row['from'];
echo "<br/>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use DISTINCT and ORDER BY in same SELECT statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391564/how-to-use-distinct-and-order-by-in-same-select-statement)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using 'distinct' in a MySQL query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/502094/using-distinct-in-a-mysql-query)

Answer (score 1):

You are ordering by a not selected column

if you want order by `time` i think you should select this column :
 try

```
  $sql = mysql_query("SELECT `from` , max(`time`) FROM `message` 
     WHERE `to`='$username'  GROUP BY  `from` ORDER BY `time` DESC " );
```

*Grouping by not require distinct*

Comment: since you are grouping by from, I suspect that the DISTINCT clause is not required

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY `from`' at line 2

Answer (score 1):

For messages you can select rows ordered by id desc like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `message` WHERE `to`='username' ORDER BY id DESC
```

Sender list you can get like this:

```
SELECT MAX(`id`),`from` FROM `message` WHERE `to`='username' GROUP BY `from`  ORDER BY MAX(`id`) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not order messages by time.
The best practice is to having unique autoincrement `id` column in `message` table and ordering messages by they's ids

Comment: I even tried from using the ID as you stated but it didn't worked either.

Comment: What do you exactly want? To get list of messages ordered by time or list of senders ordered by time?

Comment: I want to get list of messages ordered by time and the sender name doesn't get repeated too.